# JSON Array Iteration - Tree Traversing in Mulesoft

Tags: arrays, json, xml, dataweave, mule4

Input JSON:

```
{
    "id": "/",
    "code": "/",
    "typeCode": "CPC",
    "timeStamp": "2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00",
    "childList": [
        {
            "id": "577-1-1",
            "code": "1111",
            "name": "Electronics-1-1",
            "displayName": "Electronics-1-1",
            "active": true,
            "languageCode": "en",
            "typeCode": "CPC",
            "childList": [
                {
                    "id": "579-2-1",
                    "code": "2222",
                    "name": "Calculators-2-1",
                    "displayName": "Calculators-2-1",
                    "active": true,
                    "languageCode": "en",
                    "typeCode": "CPC",
                    "childList": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "509-2-2",
                    "code": "3333",
                    "name": "Oven-2-2",
                    "displayName": "Oven-2-2",
                    "active": true,
                    "languageCode": "en",
                    "typeCode": "CPC",
                    "childList": [
                        {
                            "id": "749-3-1",
                            "code": "4444",
                            "name": "MicroOven-3-1",
                            "displayName": "MicroOven-3-1",
                            "active": true,
                            "languageCode": "en",
                            "typeCode": "CPC",
                            "childList": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "549-1-2",
            "code": "5555",
            "name": "Refrigerator-1-2",
            "displayName": "Refrigerator-1-2",
            "active": true,
            "languageCode": "en",
            "typeCode": "CPC",
            "childList": []
        }
    ]
}
```

1. And the expected XML is as below - Here the categoryPath has to be noted for the complete address of childElement and has to be grouped under 1st parent childList
2. We will not know the exact child elements of any array i.e., there can be ‘n’ number of childList inside a childList
3. If childList element is empty array - we need to do mapping to xml and stop., else proceed inside that array and do the mapping for those child elements

XML Transformation:

```
<Category CategoryId="${childList.id}" CategoryPath="${childList.code}/${childList.childList.code}" Description="${childList.name}" ShortDescription="${childList.displayName}">
    <Extn ExtnSyncTS="${headers.timeStamp}"/>
</Category>
```

Expected XML:

```
<CategoryListArray>
    <CategoryList>
      <Category CategoryId="577-1-1" CategoryPath="1111" Description="Electronics-1-1" ShortDescription="Electronics-1-1">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
      </Category>
      <Category CategoryId="579-2-1" CategoryPath="1111/2222" Description="Calculators-2-1" ShortDescription="Calculators-2-1">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS=" "/>
      </Category>
      <Category CategoryId="509-2-2" CategoryPath="1111/3333" Description="Oven-2-2" ShortDescription="Oven-2-2">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
      </Category>
      <Category CategoryId="749-3-1" CategoryPath="1111/3333/4444" Description="MicroOven-3-1" ShortDescription="MicroOven-3-1">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
      </Category>
</CategoryList>
<CategoryList>
      <Category CategoryId="549-1-2" CategoryPath="5555" Description="Refrigerator-3-1" ShortDescription="Refrigerator-3-1">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
      </Category>
    </CategoryList>
</CategoryListArray>
```

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. The expected XML output should be added as text. Also describe how to map each field of the output from the input as that is not clear.

Comment: Hi @aled Can you help me on this.. This transformed xml has to be put into my target que, and im receiving this json from my source queue.., now we need to validate for null check.. for example: if id or code or name or displayname is empty in the json file, then we need to pass it to Error que in json format only - (since these are bad data and no need for transformation to xml)

Comment: Please create a new question with the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transverse the child tree using a recursive function that matches by type, so it knows how to transverse. Then you need to concatenate the current node to its childrens so they are at the same level in the output. For the arrays you should use flatMap() to avoid nesting arrays. Finally the XML output doesn't support arrays so you'll need to transform the array into an object. I used reduce() for that.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
fun mapChildren(x, timestamp, path)=
    x match {
        case o is Object -> 
            ([{
                Category @(CategoryId: o.id, CategoryPath: (if (isEmpty(path)) "" else path ++ "/") ++ o.code, Description: o.name, ShortDescription: o.displayName ): {Extn: timestamp}
            }] 
            ++ mapChildren(o.childList, timestamp, (if (isEmpty(path)) "" else path ++ "/") ++ o.code)) 
           
        case a is Array -> 
            (a flatMap mapChildren($, timestamp, path) )
               
        else -> $
    }
---
{
    CategoryList: 
        mapChildren(payload.childList, payload.timeStamp, "") 
        reduce ((item, accumulator={}) -> accumulator ++ item )
}
```

You could encapsulate it more into a function.

Comment: my response xml structure has changed as above- can you kindly help.